# How to get elements from a 2D numpy array with a list 2d indices using broadcasting?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, array-broadcasting

If I have a 2D numpy array that I want to extract elements using a list of row,col index pairs.

```
xy = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
idx = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]])
```

The for loop solution:

```
elements = list()
for i in idx:
    elements.append(xy[idx[i][0], xy[idx[i][1])
```

Output:

```
print(elements)
>> [1, 5, 9]
```

I found the solution if there idx is a list of tuples but I hoping for a solution where there is no need to convert the idx to tuples first.

Comment: Numpy has the take method for 1d indices, but still thinking on how to modify my arrays to work with it? (if it is even the right solution)

Comment: I'm confused, this was marked as duplicate, but the linked question is converting the indexes to tuples (which is what I'm trying to avoid).

Comment: Hooray, found the answer.  Since I can't add an answer here.

the solution is just use slicing:
element = xy[[idx[:,0], idx[:,1]]

Comment: The accepted answer to the linked dup question has discussed using slices : `a[idx[:,0],idx[:,1],idx[:,2]]`. We just need to read the entire posts :)

Answer (score 2):

```
    idy = zip(*idx)
    output = xy[idy]
```

Comment: Isn't zip converting idx to a list of tuples (using a loop)?

Comment: looking at zip [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) it is just using loops.